I'm trying to run a post request for a special site everything was normal for several months, Two days ago they added TURNSTILE to every request
I'm trying to run a post request for a special site everything was normal for several months, Two days ago they added CLOUDFLARE TURNSTILE to every request so now the body needs captcha token But at the same time when you send a message via the phone app it's not asking for cloudflare and it's run normal so now How can I know the request used in the phone app ?
I tried to track the phone requests but I couldn't

The app is tellonym - tellonym.me and i'm trying to get the tell send request
